# CucumberJS: Take screenshot after each step

Tags: cucumber, cucumberjs

Has anybody figured out how to take screenshot for *every* step of a scenario in cucumberjs, and attach it to the json report?

Comment: Look [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/issues/124)

Comment: I am aware of this - but this takes screenshot after the scenario completes, and not after *EACH* step

Comment: See my answer. You can apply the techniques described in the link to solve your problem. The only difference is where the snapshot is made not how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this can be done via a custom reporter, using Cucumber event handlers.

```html
browser.takeScreenshot().then((png: any) => {
     var decodedImage = new Buffer(png, 'base64');
     currentStep.embeddings.push({
      data: decodedImage.toString('base64'),
      mime_type: 'image/png'
     });
    });
```

Comment: Could you please give more information about how you implemented step hook to take screenshots?