# CucumberJS/Protractor screenshot comparison after each step

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs

I integrated CucumberJS with Protractor to write E2E tests for an **Angular** (not AngularJS) application.
Is there any easy way (maybe an already existing package) to take screenshots after each step (Given, When, Then) and compare them with some reference images? If reference images are not present, then to register the screenshot as a reference image.
The step should fail if the images are too different.

Before asking this question I read [CucumberJS: Take screenshot after each step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40832067/cucumberjs-take-screenshot-after-each-step), but that question is about taking a screenshot, not comparing.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately the npm modules that claim to do this seem abandoned (e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-image-comparison/v/1.7.0)

https://github.com/SAP/ui5-uiveri5 has a similar image comparison which could serve as an example (see docs/usage/visual testing). basically you need a custom jasmine matcher an an image comparison module such as resemblejs

Comment: Actually what I need is not a jasmine matcher, but a Cucumber custom formatter that does this.